# Deleted migration files getting executed : Laravel application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, database-migration, laravel-artisan

I hace deleted some migration files. but when i execute php artisan migrate command, error in the old migration file is showing.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL     : alter table `cushbu_notifications` add constraint
>   `cushbu_notifications_art_id_foreign` foreign key (`art_id`)
>   references `cushbu_arts` (`id`) on de     lete cascade)

Now i don't have migration file for cushbu_notifications, instead i created a new migration file for cushbu_user_notifications.I deleted the cushbu_notifications table from database, also the corresponding entry from migrations table.

Comment: have you try to run 'composer dump-autoload'?

Comment: yeah, i tried that . but not solving the issue

Comment: have you tried deleting table from database?. if you delete migration file, you should also delete table from database.

Comment: I have deleted, mentioned in the question

Comment: this answer may be relevant: [safely remove migration In laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871413/safely-remove-migration-in-laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After manually deleting migration files, clear cache by below command, and then migrate

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the entry from the migration table. and also remove references if that used in another migrations file.

Comment: i have removed, mentioned in the question

Comment: also remove references if that used in another migrations file

Comment: no other migration files only a single migration file exist

Answer (score 1):

Deleting migration files manually will not remove them from the Laravel cache. You can remove them by executing this.

```
php artisan optimize
```