# How to remove all migrations from a Laravel project but keep the tables and fields

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.7, laravel-migrations

I've decided to remove all the migrations from a Laravel 5.7 project as I would rather create/update the tables by hand. I've realised that data can still be loaded from the database without any migration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the migration files and data in the migrations table but keep the other tables and fields.

Steps modified from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830269/9562525).

- Backup the database. [official link for mysqldump command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html).
- Delete all the files in the migrations folder `\database\migrations\`
- Delete the contents of the `migrations` table in MySQL `delete from migrations;`
- In the project folder run `composer dump-autoload`

---

If you are managing your tables by hand remember to add the

`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL

`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL

fields to your tables if you want to use Laravels built in timestamps functionality. If you don't want to use it leave them out and add the following line to the model:

`public $timestamps = false;`

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937565/disable-laravels-eloquent-timestamps) for more details on the timestamps.